# Get ID right after it's set, on same page

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

The ThreadID in Thread_Body needs to be the id of Thread_Titles id.
How would I go about doing this?

```
if (isset($_POST['Post_Thread'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['Post_Title'])) {
        echo "No Title No Thread.";
    } else {
        $Sec = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sec']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Thread_Titles (Name, Section, Posted, Poster, Updated) VALUES('".cleanPost($_POST['Post_Title'])."', '".$Sec."', '".time()."', '".$ULN->Username."', '".time()."') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    if (empty($_POST['Post_Body'])) {
        echo "No Body No Thread.";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Thread_Replies (Body, Posted, Poster, ThreadID) VALUES('".cleanPost($_POST['Post_Body'])."', '".time()."', '".$ULN->Username."', '".$ThreadID."') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

This is the code all expect the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Thread_Titles (Name, Section, Posted, Poster, Updated) VALUES('".cleanPost($_POST['Post_Title'])."', '".$Sec."', '".time()."', '".$ULN->Username."', '".time()."') ") or die(mysql_error());  
$ThreadID = mysql_insert_id();
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I have been told this, but yet i still have no idea what you guys are talking about.
I am still learning lot and i go by videos and stuff i learn from other people so...

Also What will `mysql_insert_id()` do?

Comment: Click on all of the links and you will have all of your answers. :)

Comment: Holy crap, that simple? Thank you very much.
Also thanks for sharing all that other stuff I will look into it right now.